# How to use required in implode PHP

Tags: php

I have a problem at the moment. It is about the use of required in an implode element in PHP.

The current project is about assembling styled files with a $ _GET parameter. So that I do not need multiple `<link>` tags, but only one.

Here an example: 
https://stylesheet-helper.bucketfront.com/css?sheet=minify

You now include the minify.php File. To include also the style.php File I created an explode / implode element. With it the new URL Looks like this: https://stylesheet-helper.bucketfront.com/css?sheet=style|minify 
But now I have an 500 Server error because I don´t know how to include the required Element into the implode element.

Now the code:

```
<!-- language: lang-php -->
    <?php
    header("Content-type: text/css");
    $sheet = $_GET["sheet"];
    $styles = explode("|", $sheet );
    $value = implode("", $styles);
    require ('assets/' . $value . '.php');
    ?>
```

How can I input the require element `require ('assets/' . $value . '.php');` into the `implode("", $styles);` element so that it outputs both files.

This is an example with HTML Tags included into the implode Element. I think this is also possible with the required element:

```
<!-- language: lang-php -->
    <?php
    header("Content-type: text/css");
    $sheet = $_GET["sheet"];
    $styles = explode("|", $sheet );
    $value = "<span>" . implode("</span>&nbsp;<span>", $styles) . "</span>";
    echo $value;
    // Output with URL /css?sheet=style|minify: <span>style</span>&nbsp;<span>minify</span>
    ?>
```

I hope you can help me.

Thank you very much.

Additional:

- Code of the .htaccess file:

  `RewriteEngine  on
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.php$ [NC]
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$  $1.php [QSA]`
- All Files on the bucketfront subdomain stylesheet-helper:

`.htaccess`
`css.php`
`/assets/minify.php`
`/assets/style.php`

Comment: your question is not clear. why are you using implode? you should loop through the styles you got from explode and use `require` on each of them

Comment: I thought I can include the required element like i did with the `span` Tags before. But thanks for your reply. Do you mean something like this to loop the styles from explode? https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_looping_for.asp

Comment: I don't know from where the `...css?sheet=style|minify` request is being generated. if it is from a html (web browser) then you cannot send 2 files for a single request. You can concatenate both files to a single file and send reply as a single file.

Comment: The request is being generated from https://stylesheet-helper.bucketfront.com/css?sheet=style|minify. I thought I can do it like Google with the Google Fonts API. They also use a technology like this. Example: https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans|Roboto I thought including both files into one file is already a concatenation.

Comment: @bansi thank very much you solved my problem. I used the loop function I found on W3schools to include each file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should include all files as one (cannot send back more than 1 reply for a single request in HTTP protocol). Added comment in code

```
<?php
header("Content-type: text/css");
$sheet = $_GET["sheet"];
$styles = explode("|", $sheet );
// include each file.
// If your styles are simple stylesheets (no php parsing required) 
// try using readfile instead of include
foreach ($styles as $value){
    include ('assets/' . $value . '.php');
    // readfile method
    // readfile ('assets/' . $value . '.php');

}
```

Additional reference: [readfile](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php)

Comment: Thank you @bansi. I will use this version.

Answer (score 0):

This is the final code I used:

```
<?php
header("Content-type: text/css");
$sheet = $_GET["sheet"];
$styles = explode("|", $sheet );
$output = $styles; 
foreach ($output as $value) {
require ('assets/' . $value . '.php');
}
?>
```

I´ve looped it like bansi said. Source: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_looping_for.asp

Comment: if you are not planning to use php code in your style sheets, try using `readfile` it is much more efficient, as it don't need the overhead of a php parser to be run on the file. `readfile ('assets/' . $value . '.php');`

Comment: Oh thank you. No im not using any PHP Code in the stylesheets. Its only CSS Code. I will use readfile instead the include. Thank you @bansi. You´ve solved my problem. :)